# Is it possible to run java from Python in order to create a .png?

Tags: java, python, shell

I currently have a working java application which from a String renders a .png file. When run from cmd it produces the image in the directory I want. However, when I've tried calling it from Python using

```
subprocess.call(["java", "-jar", "C:\\path\to\my\jarFile\file.jar", 
                                                        inputString], shell = True)
```

no image is created. How can I make it create an image?

Any advice is helpful!

Comment: Is it a typo or do you have `\` and `\\` in your path?

Comment: Do you use relative paths in your java programm? Also is the file overwritten from java?

Comment: add logging to both your python and your java application to help with your debugging.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows platform but don't you need double `\ ` in your path? Such as `C:\\path\\to\\my\\jarFile\\file.jar`?

Comment: I've tried it with both relative and absolute paths and have not had success yet.  And is it wrong to have "\" in my path? I've used it with Popen and haven't had any issues. And I have `\\` where Python recommends it. Tried editing it so that I have double backslashes everywhere but did not help unfortunately.

Comment: You need to escape every backslash with a backslash: `C:\\\\path\\to\\my\\jarFile\\file.jar`

Comment: You need to use `shell=False`, or else the *shell* is passed those arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the process output message to debug it, example code:

```
inputString = ''
ps = subprocess.Popen(["java", "-jar", "C:\\path\to\my\jarFile\file.jar", inputString],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
val = ps.stdout.read()
print("val: " + val)
```

and in my pc, it output error like this:

> val: Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\path  o\my\jarFileile.jar

Comment: Solved it, had some syntax error. Thanks for the help!